# How to fix "Can not find local variable" error?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Good Day developers , im just building this app using spring boot , and in one of its methods i got this error:"Cannot find local variable 'prods'".Basically i just obtain a list of ids assigned to products and from there start to develope functions that considering this ids and other app requirements might throw a result.But in my last forloop i initialize for second time a variable of type Product with a diferent name(prods) despite of having initialized and save it  before in former function with different name(product), but then consistently gives me that error , even though if i debug not letting me to find a possible source of the issue.
Any idea about why is this happening .Thanks in advance!!!!.Im sharing the part of my code where the problem is.Thanks!!!

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mini/all_products/allpurchase_view",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity <Map<String,Object>>addNewPurchase( Authentication authentication,RequestBody List<Long> products){
    Map<String,Object> dto=new HashMap<>();
    User user=userDetailslogged(authentication);

    if(authentication==null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(makeMapResponse("Error","User No Authenticated"), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    if(user==null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(makeMapResponse("Error","Register This User Please "), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

    Double pricePurchase = 0.0;
    List<Product>purchaseProducts=new ArrayList<>();

    for (Long id : products){
        Product product=productRepository.getOne(id);
        product.setProductStock(product.getProductStock()-1);
        productRepository.save(product);
        pricePurchase=pricePurchase+product.getProductPrice();
        purchaseProducts.add(product);
    }

    Double DiscountMore5 = 0.0;
    if(purchaseProducts.size() > 5)
        DiscountMore5 = pricePurchase * 0.10;
    else
        DiscountMore5 = 0.0;

    Map<Long,Integer> counter = new HashMap<Long,Integer>();
    Double discountEqual4 = 0.0;

    for(Long productId:products)
         if(counter.containsKey(productId))
             counter.put(productId,counter.get(productId)+1);
         else
             counter.put(productId,1);

    for(Map.Entry<Long,Integer> repeated :counter.entrySet()) {
       // This is where the problem is:
       **Product prods**=productRepository.getOne(repeated.getKey());
        if(repeated.getKey() == prods.getId() && repeated.getValue() >= 4)
            discountEqual4 = prods.getProductPrice()*Math.floor(repeated.getValue()/4);
    }

    Double totalDiscount=discountEqual4+DiscountMore5;

    Purchase purchase1=new Purchase(new Date(),user,products.size(),pricePurchase,totalDiscount,purchaseProducts);
    purchaseRepository.save(purchase1);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(makeMapResponse("Success","Product Added"), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: It means that it can't find the variable. Either you misspelled it's name, or it's out of scope, meaning that you declared it in one set of curly brackets `{}` but try to reference it in another.

Comment: Holla Schred, the variable is not misspelled, but could you explain me how could be out of scope, is the last loop in the code , and even though when im debbuging  evaluating the variable itself  that error shows up.Any idea?

Comment: Please show us more of what the error says.

Comment: plain as that ....."Cannot find local variable 'prods'"

Comment: Does it happen only  when you debug?  Which IDE you are using?

Comment: yes ...im using intellij comunnity version 2019.3

Comment: I found this code snippet: `**Product prods**` in the `for` loop that processes the `counter.entrySet()`.

Comment: yes cause im just pointing where the problem is

Comment: Can you share your whole error log?

Comment: there is no log of error ...application runs without throwing error , but the discount doesnt update due to this no recognizable variable

Comment: @EnriqueGF were you able to solve this? Even I am facing the same issue in IntelliJ?